# How to know the status of mongodb functions in Java

Tags: mongodb-java

If a function call is done in java like:

```
collection.update(match, new BasicDBObject("$pull", update));
```

How can I know the number of documents updated in database after this statement execution?

And my other problem is, that I want to remove an element from an array in a document, if that element exists  the collection. How can I do that easily? Should I query to find whether it is present in collection and then delete it or is there any other easier way?

Answer (score 0):

1) The [DBCollection.html#update](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method returns a WriteResult object that contains a *n* property, [which contains the number of documents affected in the write operation.](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html#getN%28%29)

2) I think there is no way to do that in a single operation. If, at insert moment, the element is already on array of other document, you could do an update to remove the element from array. Something like that:

```
DBObject newElement = ...

DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("array", newElement)
    .get();

DBObject update = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .push("$pull")
        .add("array", newElement)
    .pop()
    .get(); 

collection.update(query, update);
collection.insert(newElement);
```